# powerquery custom function with cumulative row total and cumulative column total

Tags: powerbi, powerquery

i may be in need a solution to the problem i have.

have created a custom function create n number of columns and fill up a value for each row for the newly created columns.

However am kind of in need with restricting the fill up when either cumulative row total breaches certain value or each column total threshold of fixed value

what i want to achieve is in the screenshot, any help would be great
input data: https://snipboard.io/Liar7m.jpg

output data: https://snipboard.io/9uTEyM.jpg

```
let
    AddColumns = (existingTable as table, maxSlots as number, CRcolname as text) =>
        let
            columnsToAdd = List.Transform({1..maxSlots}, each Text.From(_)),
            addColumn = (table, columnName) => Table.AddColumn(table, columnName, each 0, type number), //type number
            newTable = List.Accumulate(columnsToAdd, existingTable, (table, columnName) => addColumn(table, columnName)),
            fillcracrosscolumns = (tt as table) => //function to fill up cr value across
                let
                    columnNamesToFill = List.Transform({1..maxSlots}, each Text.From(_)),
                    
                    fillRow = (row as record) =>
                        let
                            crValue = Record.Field(row, CRcolname),
                            newColumns = List.Transform(columnNamesToFill, each Text.From(_)),
                            updatedRow = Record.Combine({row, Record.FromList(List.Repeat({crValue}, maxSlots), newColumns)})
                        in
                            updatedRow,
                    updatedRows = Table.TransformRows(tt, fillRow),
                    updatedTable = Table.FromRecords(updatedRows)
                    //ChangeColumnTypeToNumber = (tt as table) =>
                    //    let
                    //        columnsToChange = List.Transform({1..maxSlots}, each Text.From(_)),
                    //        updatedTable = Table.TransformColumnTypes(tt, List.Transform(columnsToChange, each {_, type number}))
                    //    in
                    //        updatedTable,
                    //finaltable = ChangeColumnTypeToNumber(updatedTable)

                in
                    updatedTable, //finaltable,
            fintable = fillcracrosscolumns(newTable)
        in
            fintable
in
    AddColumns
```

Comment: What does your input data look like. What is the output data supposed to look like and why  What does your example not do that you want

Comment: each cell should respect the row total threshold for each row and each column must respect its own threshold and the value to be filled for each row respecting both thresholds

Comment: https://snipboard.io/9uTEyM.jpg
what i want to achieve is here in the pic. please help me with approach to achieve this threshold for row and column

Comment: You have shown your output data. What is your input data?

Comment: input data is upto column C in screenshot

Comment: input data screenshot
https://snipboard.io/Liar7m.jpg

Comment: Thanks for your response @horseyride. Let's wait and see if anyone else has the answer

Comment: What might be the maximum number of rows and columns?

Comment: we never know the number of columns but i am trying to process these for less than 100 rows

Comment: Can we assume that `max value` will always be an integer multiple of `fillup value`?

Comment: I have developed an algorithm that works in PQ. However, it is exceedingly slow. Would using VBA be an option if it is faster?

Comment: @RonRosenfeld i wish this task was that easy... yes max value is an integer multiple of fillup value... I did try other steps where i got steps to do cumulative column total and then row column total and then remove those 2 columns to derive at the new column... this step is taking is too painful to run as the memory is holding up for a long time even with Table.Buffer for each step

Answer (score 1):

The algorithm I developed includes:

- Check each added column so as NOT to include the next fillup if it will cause the Column Max to be exceeded
- As each column is added, check the sum of the row

  - if the sum of the row + one fillup is greater than the Max for the row, change the fillup to zero

In Power Query, for 8 rows and seven columns, the procedure took over one minute to run using Power Query in Power BI Desktop.  Using Power Query in Excel, it took more than three minutes to run

Using VBA in excel, the procedure took a fraction of a second!

Obviously, in this instance I would recommend VBA over PQ, especially since you wrote you may have over 1000 columns and 100 rows.

I only showed the strictly necessary input (and output) data. The rest can be easily added if needed.

Here are the VBA routines:

```
Const numCols As Long = 7
Const colTotal As Long = 210
Option Explicit

Sub expand()
    Dim vRes() As Variant, vSrc As Variant, vCol As Variant
    Dim lFillup() As Long, lMaxVal() As Long, corrFillup() As Long
    Dim sHdrs() As String
    
    Dim rRes As Range
    Dim I As Long, J As Long
    
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet16").ListObjects("Table26")
        vSrc = .DataBodyRange
        ReDim sHdrs(1 To .ListColumns.Count)
            For I = 1 To .ListColumns.Count
                sHdrs(I) = .ListColumns(I).Name
            Next I
    End With
    
    ReDim lFillup(1 To UBound(vSrc))
    ReDim corrFillup(1 To UBound(vSrc))
    ReDim lMaxVal(1 To UBound(vSrc))
    ReDim vCol(1 To numCols)
    ReDim vRes(0 To UBound(vSrc, 1), 1 To UBound(vSrc, 2) + numCols)
    
For I = 1 To UBound(vSrc)
    lFillup(I) = vSrc(I, 2)
    lMaxVal(I) = vSrc(I, 3)
Next I

For I = 1 To numCols
    corrFillup = procFillup(lFillup, lMaxVal, vCol)
    vCol(I) = procCol(corrFillup)
Next I

'headers
For J = 1 To 3
    vRes(0, J) = sHdrs(J)
Next J

For J = 4 To numCols + 3
    vRes(0, J) = CStr(J - 3)
Next J

'copy first three columns to vRes
For I = 1 To UBound(vSrc, 1)
    For J = 1 To 3
        vRes(I, J) = vSrc(I, J)
    Next J
Next I


'write new columns to vRes
For I = 1 To UBound(vRes, 1)
    For J = 1 To numCols
        vRes(I, J + 3) = vCol(J)(I)
    Next J
Next I
    


With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet16")
    Set rRes = .Cells(14, "Q").Resize(rowsize:=UBound(vRes, 1) + 1, columnsize:=UBound(vRes, 2))
    With rRes
        .EntireColumn.Clear
        .Value = vRes
        .Style = "Output"
        .EntireColumn.AutoFit
    End With
End With


End Sub

Function procCol(fillup() As Long) As Long()
    Dim I As Long
    Dim lSum As Long
    Dim lTemp() As Long
    
ReDim lTemp(1 To UBound(fillup))

lSum = 0
For I = 1 To UBound(fillup)
    lTemp(I) = IIf(lSum + fillup(I) > colTotal, 0, fillup(I))
    lSum = lSum + lTemp(I)
Next I

procCol = lTemp

End Function

Function procFillup(fillup() As Long, lmax() As Long, arr As Variant) As Long()
    Dim I As Long, J As Long, lSum As Long, lCols As Long
    Dim lTemp() As Long: ReDim lTemp(1 To UBound(fillup))
    
For lCols = 1 To UBound(arr)
    If IsEmpty(arr(lCols)) Then Exit For
Next lCols

    If lCols = 1 Then
        procFillup = fillup
        Exit Function
    Else
        lCols = lCols - 1
    End If

        For J = 1 To UBound(arr(1))
            lSum = 0
            For I = 1 To lCols
                lSum = lSum + arr(I)(J)
            Next I
                lTemp(J) = IIf((lSum + fillup(J)) > lmax(J), 0, fillup(J))
            'Stop
        Next J
'Stop

procFillup = lTemp
End Function
```

Here are the Power Query routines:

***Main Code***

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table26"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"rowindex", Int64.Type}, {"fillup value", Int64.Type}, {"max value", Int64.Type}}),

ColTot=210,
numCols=7,

    #"Add Columns" = List.Accumulate(
        List.Buffer(List.Transform({1..numCols}, each Text.From(_))),
        #"Changed Type",
        (s,c)=>
            Table.FromColumns(
                Table.ToColumns(s)
                & {fnProcCol(fnProcFillup(s),ColTot)},
            Table.ColumnNames(s) & {c}
    ))
in
    #"Add Columns"
```

***fnProcCol***

```
(nums as list, max as number)=>

let 
    //total = List.Sum(nums),
    //diff = total - max,
 
    arr = List.Generate(
        ()=> [t = if nums{0} > max then 0 else nums{0}, 
              n = nums{0},
              idx=0],
        each [idx] < List.Count(nums),
        each [t = if ([t] + nums{[idx]+1}) > max then [t] else [t] + nums{[idx]+1},
              n = if ([t] + nums{[idx]+1}) > max then 0 else nums{[idx]+1},
              idx = [idx]+1],
        each {[n]})

in List.Combine(arr)
```

***fnProcFillup***

```
(t as table)=>

let 
    fillup = List.Buffer(t[fillup value]),
    maxvalue = List.Buffer(t[max value]),
    #"Corrected Fillup" = if Table.ColumnCount(t) = 3 then t[fillup value] else
    
    List.Accumulate(
        {0..Table.RowCount(t)-1},
        {},
        (s, c)=> s & {
            if List.Sum(
                List.RemoveFirstN(
                    Record.FieldValues((t{c})),3)) < t{c}[max value] 
            then t{c}[fillup value] else 0})
in 
    #"Corrected Fillup"
```

***Data Source***
[image]

***Output***
[image]

Comment: looks working and unfortunately too slow. on increasing column length even after overnight refresh, still running. Thanks for your efforts though

Comment: @VasanthaSarangapani Did you try the VBA code?

Comment: yeah... it worked but my source is not excel to process the info in excel

Comment: @VasanthaSarangapani What is your source?

Comment: my input source is json for now

Comment: @VasanthaSarangapani It's not much trouble to parse JSON in VBA, but if python works why not use that?

Comment: yeah, i have posted my python code as answer

Answer (score 0):

I used python temporarily to bring out the logic i badly wanted to build in powerquery itself

```
import pandas as pd
import json
emp_string = '[{"rowindex": 1, "cr": 60, "maxval": 180}, {"rowindex": 2, "cr": 80, "maxval": 400}, {"rowindex": 3, "cr": 20, "maxval": 60}, {"rowindex": 4, "cr": 4, "maxval": 16}, {"rowindex": 5, "cr": 50, "maxval": 150}, {"rowindex": 6, "cr": 40, "maxval": 120}, {"rowindex": 7, "cr": 60, "maxval": 120}, {"rowindex": 8, "cr": 50, "maxval": 150}]'
data = json.loads(emp_string)
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
maxcols = 52
maxthreshold = 210

def is_numeric(s):
    try:
        float(s)
        return True
    except ValueError:
        return False

def cumulative_sum_within_threshold(column, threshold):
    cumulative_sum = 0
    new_column = []
    for value in column:
        if cumulative_sum + value <= threshold:
            cumulative_sum += value
            new_column.append(value)
        else:
            new_column.append(0)
    return new_column
def rowsum(row, threshold,colnam):
    numeric_columns = [col for col in df.columns if is_numeric(col)]
    num_row_total = row[colnam] if row[numeric_columns].sum() <= threshold else 0
    return num_row_total

for x in range(0,maxcols,1):
    colname = x
    df[colname] = df['cr']
    df[colname] = df.apply(lambda row: rowsum(row, row['maxval'], colname), axis=1)
    df[colname] = cumulative_sum_within_threshold(df[colname],maxthreshold)

print(df)
print()
#output this dataframe to json for powerbi
```

[image: final achieved output]